# C# PowerShell Failed to connect to AzureAD in web app only

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

I use the below C# codes to run PowerShell scripts to connect to Azure AD. The PS scripts work fine in PS ISE. The C# codes work fine in a console app.  Verbose output shows successful connection with information about Account, Environment, TenantId,

When the same C# codes run as code behind in my web app, the powershell.Invoke() step took 30 seconds to return and failed to connect to AzureAD. Errors are shown below.

I have verified that the steps that import AzureAD module, create $UserName, $Password, and $Credential variables work.

```
private void ConnectAzureAD()
{
    string PSModuleName = "C:\\PowerShellModules\\AzureAD";
    string loginName = "myID@mydomain.com";
    string loginPwd = "myPassword";

    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    try
    {
        powershell.AddScript("Import-Module -Name '" + PSModuleName + "' -Force");
        powershell.AddScript("$UserName = '" + loginName + "'");
        powershell.AddScript("$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString '" + loginPwd + "'-AsPlainText -Force -Verbose");
        powershell.AddScript("$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName, $Password -Verbose");
        powershell.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential -Verbose");
        Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powershell.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

**Powershell.Streams.Verbose:**

```
{Performing the operation "Connect-AzureAD" on target "Establishing a PowerShell session connected to {0} environment.".}
    InvocationInfo: Command = {Connect-AzureAD}
    Message: "Performing the operation \"Connect-AzureAD\" on target \"Establishing a PowerShell session connected to {0} environment.\"."
    PipelineIterationInfo: Count = 2
```

**Powershell.Streams.Error:**

```
{One or more errors occurred.: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}
    CategoryInfo: {AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException}
    ErrorDetails: null
    Exception: {"One or more errors occurred.: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
    FullyQualifiedErrorId: "Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD"
    InvocationInfo: Command = {Connect-AzureAD}
    PipelineIterationInfo: Count = 2
    ScriptStackTrace: "at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1"
    TargetObject: null

{One or more errors occurred.}
    CategoryInfo: {AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException}
    ErrorDetails: null
    Exception: Count = 1
    FullyQualifiedErrorId: "Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD"
    InvocationInfo: Command = {Connect-AzureAD}
    PipelineIterationInfo: Count = 2
    ScriptStackTrace: "at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1"
    TargetObject: null

{Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}
    CategoryInfo: {AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], NullReferenceException}
    ErrorDetails: null
    Exception: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
    FullyQualifiedErrorId: "Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD"
    InvocationInfo: Command = {Connect-AzureAD}
    PipelineIterationInfo: Count = 2
    ScriptStackTrace: "at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1"
    TargetObject: null

{One or more errors occurred.: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}
    CategoryInfo: {NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException}
    ErrorDetails: null
    Exception: {"One or more errors occurred.: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
    FullyQualifiedErrorId: "Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD"
    InvocationInfo: Command = {Connect-AzureAD}
    PipelineIterationInfo: Count = 0
    ScriptStackTrace: "at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1"
    TargetObject: null
```

Comment: Can you please try calling $Credential.password.MakeReadOnly() before calling it in connect-AzureAd command and then check $Credential.Password.Length before credentials and after connect-AzureAd.

Answer (score 0):

- The password  credentials object may have got  cleared after the call
  for security reasons in azure active directory .
- To re-use the password by calling in connect-azuread call you should
  make it read-only before the cmdlet call .

Work around:

1. Please try calling $Credential.password.MakeReadOnly() before
   calling it in connect-AzureAd command and then check
   $Credential.Password.Length before credentials and after
   connect-AzureAd.

*example:*

```
$Credential.Password.Length
...
$Credential.password.MakeReadOnly()
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
$Credential.Password.Length
```

(or)
2. Try to copy original password while calling

```
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password.Copy())
```

3. Also please read the points under [adding-a-credential-parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/add-credentials-to-powershell-functions?view=powershell-7.2#adding-a-credential-parameter)
   and see if you can add ValidateNotNull() attribute to check the
   credentials .

If issue remains, it may be possibly due to the .net or c# code version. Try to upgrade it to latest version.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I tried both (1) and (2).  The password variable lengths remain the same before and after, and I still get the same errors. Both console app and web app are using .NET framework 4.6.1 and compiled with same Visual Studio IDE. Since the codes run fine in the console app, I don't think the root cause for the web app failure is related to .NET framework.